# Реализация семафора Java

Tags: java, многопоточность, семафоры

1 Поток:

```
public class First implements Runnable {
    private Semaphore semaphore;

    public First(Semaphore semaphore) {
        this.semaphore = semaphore;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            semaphore.enter();
            System.out.println(1);
            semaphore.leave();
        }
    }
}
```

2 поток:

```
public class Second implements Runnable {
    private Semaphore semaphore;

    public SequentalCleaner(Semaphore semaphore) {
        this.semaphore = semaphore;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            semaphore.enter();
            System.out.println(2);
            semaphore.leave();
        }
    }
}
```

Семафор:

```
public class Semaphore {
    private int cur;

    public Semaphore(int cur) {
        this.cur = cur;
    }

    public void enter() {
        while(cur == 0){
        }
            --cur;
    }
    public void leave(){
        ++cur;
    }
}
```

Это не синхронизировано. Как сделать синхронизированным?
Вывод при запуске потоков:

> 2 1 2 1 2 1 1 1

или, например

> 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2

Т.е. они даже не заканчивают свою работу.

Comment: AtomicInteger например

Comment: Зачем в методе `leave` условие `while (cur != 0){}`? o_O

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev: synchronized не покатит, т. к. на время ожидания в enter блокировку нужно отпускать!

Comment: Решил эту проблему, добавление в конец метода leave цикл while(cur != 0){} теперь выводится последовательно но работу потоки не завершают

Comment: Вы в курсе что такой цикл может не завершиться никогда?

Comment: да в курсе, я честно не знаю как иначе более менее синхронизировать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Хотя конечно варианты реализации семафоров лучше в книгах по многопоточности посмотреть, вот вариант "велосипеда":

```
public class TestSemaphor {
    private final static int NThreads = 60;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(3);

    Thread[] threads = new Thread[NThreads];
    for (int i = 0; i < NThreads; i++) {
        threads[i] = new Thread(new Runner(semaphore, i));
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < NThreads; i++) {
        threads[i].start();
    }
}
}

class Runner implements Runnable {
private Semaphore semaphore;
private int label;

public Runner(Semaphore semaphore, int label) {
    this.semaphore = semaphore;
    this.label = label;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    int r = 0;
    System.out.println("thread " + label + " start");

    semaphore.enter();
    System.out.println("thread " + label + "  is working");
    for (int k = 0; k < 10000; k++) {
        r = new Random().nextInt();
    }
    ;
    System.out.println("thread " + label + "  has ended work");
    semaphore.leave();

    System.out.println("thread " + label + " end " + r);
}
}

class Semaphore {
private int curMax;
private int cur;
private Object lock = new Object();

public Semaphore(int curMax) {
    this.curMax = curMax;
}

public void enter() {
    synchronized (lock) {
        cur++;
        if (cur > curMax) {
            try {
                lock.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }

        }
    }

}

public void leave() {
    synchronized (lock) {
        cur--;
        lock.notify();
    }

}
}
```

Собственно идея такая: синхронизации используется только для того, чтобы обновить счетчик очереди. Если при этом у нас потоков больше чем надо, то отправляем текущий поток в ожидание. При освобождении семафора вызываем на случайном ожидающем потоке notify. Обратите внимание что синхронизация идет по одному и тому же объекту - поэтому happens before присутствует